# RAM Capacity of Mac Studio with M2 Ultra for inference of 65B LLM

Tags: large-language-models

How much RAM would be needed on Mac Studio M2 Ultra for inferring from a 65B LLM model. There are three options: 64GB, 128GB and 192GB. If using Apple M2 Ultra with 24‑core CPU, 76‑core GPU, 32‑core Neural Engine with 192GB Unified Memory, how would be the performance of the model?